# Apex Get Account Record Ids where Contact First Name is in LIST ( using AND Condition )

Tags: salesforce, apex

In Salesforce I would like to retrieve AccountIds where its related Contact FirstName must have values in list of String. List of string is {'Test','User'}. I would need to find all Accounts where Contact first Name has both Test and User as related Contacts,

I am trying as below but the below query will show accounts where even 1 value matches as Contact First Name.

`List<String> names = new List<String>{'Test','User'}; List<Account> accountList =         [ Select Id from Account Where Id IN         (Select AccountId FROM Contacts where FirstName LIKE :names)];`

Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM Account
WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE LastName = 'Test')
AND Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE LastName = 'User')
```

But it'll work only 2 times, you can't write 3rd "IN" like that (see [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164366/maximum-2-semi-join-sub-selects-are-allowed)).

If you need a more generic solution that can take lists of any size you'd have to run "my" queries in loop, 2 names at a time, save results to some `Set<Id>` or Map, play with functions like `myset.retainAll(idsFromCurrentLoopQuery)`... Of course query in a loop is bit evil too.